# IntelliJ IDEA: Ant build.xml — attribute is not allowed here

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ant

[image: Screenshot]

I'm use intellij idea and my project's build tool is Ant
Some errors make me sick.
What does that error mean?

Answer (score 0):

IDE is not able to resolve `sftp` task definition, there are related issues in IntelliJ IDEA tracker:

- [IDEA-14097](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-14097) IDEA Ant editor not recognizing sshexec & scp tasks
- [IDEA-80098](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80098) Cannot resolve symbol 'scp' in IntelliJ IDEA 11 Ant build script on Ubuntu Linux

Where did you get ssh/sftp task for Ant? What jars did you add to Ant classpath to make them work? Please show the taskdefs.